# recursive function not working Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the first index in an array`s element is equal to the input,if it is i want it to increment and check  for the next index and so on.but my code only does it for the first index,increments and then returns to the first index again.why ?

```
    var i=0

    function compareInput(array){


    if(result[i]==document.getElementById('input')){
         i++;
         compareInput(array);
    }
    else{
       console.log('not equal');
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason to do this recursively instead of using a `for` loop?

Comment: @pun - every time `compareInput` is executed `i = 0`. If you don't want to reset it, set `i = 0` outside the scope of the  `compareInput` function.

Comment: @pun: Right, you don't reset it. But every time you call `compareInput`, it creates a new `i` variables that is initialised to `0`.

Comment: Unless you are doing this for some school work to learn recursion just use a for loop.

Comment: Where is `result` defined?

Comment: `document.getElementById('input')` gets you the element, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to compare input with a recursive function.
I used function as return because **i variable** scope, where  **i variable** is only available in compareInput function, can be acessed inside function, that is inside of compareInput function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="input"></input>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function compareInput(array){
      var i=0;

      return function(array){
            if(array[i]== document.getElementById('input')){
                 i++;
                 compareInput(array);
                 console.log("equal %d",1);
            }
            else{
               console.log('not equal');
           }
      }
 }

var compare = compareInput();
compare([document.getElementById('input')]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some different approaches for finding a string in an array.

```js
function isInArray(i, a){
    return  !!~a.indexOf(i);
}

function isInArrayWithLoop(i, a) {
    var c;
    for (c = 0; c < a.length; c++) {
        if (i === a[c]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function isInArrayWithRecursion(i, a, c) {
    // initialize c with o if not given
    c = c || 0;
    // return false if not c < a.length
    // if c < a.length
    // then return the result of the vomparison with the specified element and i
    // if false, return the result of a new call of recusion with an increased counter
    return c < a.length && (i === a[c] || isInArrayWithRecursion(i, a, c + 1));
}

function isInArrayWithSome(i, a) {
    return a.some(function(aa) {
        return i === aa;
    });
}

// direct approach
document.write(isInArray('black', ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'])+'<br>');
document.write(isInArray('yellow', ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'])+'<br>');

// loop approach
document.write(isInArrayWithLoop('black', ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']) + '<br>');
document.write(isInArrayWithLoop('yellow', ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']) + '<br>');

// recursion approach
document.write(isInArrayWithRecursion('black', ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']) + '<br>');
document.write(isInArrayWithRecursion('yellow', ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']) + '<br>');

// some approach
document.write(isInArrayWithSome('black', ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']) + '<br>');
document.write(isInArrayWithSome('yellow', ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']) + '<br>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Everytime compareInput is called, you set `var i = 0;`, therefore the if will always be `if (result[0] == document.getElementById('input'))`.
Also, `document.getElementById('')` will get you the element object, not the value, I suppose your arrays is made of values instead.

Put a `.value` and `var i = 0`; outside the scope of the function.